# Meteor 0.9.2 remote connection issue

Tags: meteor

Not sure if it's just a coincidence or a bug but after updating to 0.9.2 I lost my remote connections to any of my Meteor apps. localhost:3000 works fine but remote access to host:3000 or any other port I try cannot connect.

Comment: What do you mean by "remote access"? How is your server configured?

Comment: I can run the app from localhost:3000 or whatever port I configure but I cannot access the app from any other computers on the network. Everything was fine up until the .9.2 update.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same symptoms with the new Meteor (0.9.2.1), I was able to connect fine on my development server using localhost:3000, but I received an error when attempting to connect to that server using the NETBIOS name (which I have been doing successfully since Blaze).  Example URL:

v-as-nodejs:3000

This worked fine before but does not with the latest Meteor.

I was also able to overcome this issue by specifying an IP address and port explicitly in the Meteor server startup command:

meteor --port 192.168.1.108:3000

What is interesting is that it seems as long as the IP address in the --port parameter matches the private network address of the server, you can still connect to your server using a logical name.  In my case, my server is in a DMZ on my private network, and I can use the public domain name to get to the server.  I can also use the server's NETBIOS name, both work fine.

I don't fully understand why this would work unless node.js or Meteor is doing some internal comparison.  It is certain though that this is a matter of either the Meteor upgrade or the Node.js upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Use --port:host:port

example: meteor run --port:192.168.168.164:6969

Comment: I've tried several different ports, no go. It was fine until the .9.2 update.

Answer (score 0):

Binding to a specific IP seems to solve the problem:

meteor run -p 192.168.2.3:8080

Comment: That did it! I was only specifying the port. Did you have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, after updating to **0.9.2.1** I hope this bug will be solved very soon :)

Comment: This now has been fixed in **0.9.2.2** as you can see from the logs https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v0922